# OFFSET keyword for printing numbers in masm

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, inline-assembly

I wrote code with MSVC inline assembly where I print char arrays by printf using offset. It works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char FORMAT[] = "%s %s %s %s, %s\n";
char SURNAME[] = "Ponomarenko";
char NAME[] = "Maria";
char DESIGN[] = "Design";
char BY[] = "by";
char YEAR[] = "2020";
int YEAR1 = 2020;

void main() {
__asm { 
    mov eax, offset YEAR
    push eax
    mov eax, offset SURNAME
    push eax
    mov eax, offset NAME
    push eax
    mov eax, offset BY
    push eax
    mov eax, offset DESIGN
    push eax
    mov eax, offset FORMAT
    push eax
    mov edi, printf
    call edi

    pop ebx
    pop ebx
    pop ebx
    pop ebx
    pop ebx
} 
system("pause");
}
```

Than I tried to print number YEAR1, I tried this

```
mov eax, offset YEAR1
    push eax
```

and the result was weird, and then I wrote without offset and it worked! (of course in both cases I changed my FORMAT array)

```
mov eax, YEAR1
    push eax
```

Can you explain why offset affects printing numbers this way?

Comment: YEAR1 is a number. The `mov eax, YEAR1` depending on your compiler/assembler is probably a load from memory, which would be `mov eax, dword [YEAR1]` in NASM syntax. With the `offset` keyword it loads the address of the `int` variable. If you use, say, `%d` as the format specifier then with `offset` it will display the address numerically, rather than the value stored in that address.

Comment: You can `push offset FORMAT` instead of wasting an instruction putting the address into EAX.  And use `add esp, 4*5` instead of 5x pop into EBX.  Also, using EBX instead of EAX is going to make the compiler emit extra instructions around your asm block to save/restore EBX when it wouldn't otherwise have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in visual studio, microsoft assembler (MASM) is used where **offset** loads the address of the variable, not the value itself, you can use **offset** to invoke a function but not load a value.

please use this link as a reference:
http://www.asmcommunity.net/forums/topic/?id=15124